# Dart, never allow nested Generics?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I would like to use the nested Generics, like

```
class Class<List<T>> {
...
}
```

But always Dart Editor gives me alerts. How should I avoid these alerts?

Comment: What would that even *mean*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, Dart Editor is right. This code doesn't make any sense. Without further information on what you are trying to do (don't hesitate to update your question), I am assuming you actually mean one of those:

```darg
class MyClass<T> {
  List<T> listField;
  // other stuff
}
```

Or maybe the list itself should be generic?

```darg
void main() {
  MyClass<SomeCustomListClass<String>> instance = new MyClass();
}

class MyClass<T extends List<String>> {
  T listField;
  // ...
}
```

Or maybe everything has to be generic:

```darg
void main() {
  MyClass<String, SomeCustomListClass<String>> instance = new MyClass();
}

class MyClass<TElement, TList extends List<TElement>> {
  TList listField;
  TElement _firstListElement;
  // whatever that could be used for
}
```